# Is there a way to call a custom command after horizon has been started via CLI?

Tags: laravel, command, laravel-artisan, horizon

I am attempting to call a custom command to dispatch a job from the CLI after starting horizon.

journal:add is a custom command to add journal details to a mysql database.

```php
        $this->line('<fg=red>Migrate and refreshing databases</>');
          sleep(1);
        $this->call('migrate:refresh');
        $this->line('<fg=red>Flushing the redis queue</>');
          sleep(1);
        exec('redis-cli flushall');
          sleep(1);
        $this->line('<fg=red>Starting Horizon</>');
        $this->call('horizon');
          sleep(1);
        $this->line('<fg=red>Adding test journal</>');
        $this->call('journal:add', ['issn'=>'1098-2418']);
```

Expected results are to dispatch the journal job onto the queue after horizon has started.

Currently, the code starts Horizon but does not do anything following that.

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel Horizon` does not execute or exits, it keeps running waiting for new jobs. If you want to achieve what you want. Create two commands, first executing `Horizon`, second job dispatches the job.

Thou what you are doing, seems like a wrong approach, never been in the case where i had to group commands together in other commands. What is wrong by executing the given commands in the sequence needed?